# Rename the files while uploading

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to rename the files while uploading, but it's not renaming as I expected. Just want to add the date and the time front of the name.
      Attaching the code below.

```
if(isset($_FILES['img_ct_1'])){

$today = date("Ymd");

//prepare url
$temp_path = CDN_URL.'photos/';

$name_array = $_FILES['img_ct_1']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['img_ct_1']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['img_ct_1']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['img_ct_1']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['img_ct_1']['error'];
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/photos/';


for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],$upload_dir.time().$name_array[$i])){
        print_r ($name_array[$i]);
        $array['path'] = $temp_path.$newfilename;
        $array['success'] = true ;
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    $file = $today.time().$name_array[$i];
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], $upload_dir . $file)){
        print_r ($name_array[$i]);
        $array['path'] = $temp_path.$newfilename;
        $array['success'] = true ;
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it works :). can you help me to put this one inside a function. big help

Comment: if it helped, please upvote the answer. which part you want to put inside a function?

Comment: i did, but i think i dont have enough scores.

i want to access the function like below and return the array to $image_path

$image_path = upload_patient_doc($_FILES,'img_ct_1');